# Exposing a "dumbed-down", read-only instance of a Model in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, model

Does anyone know a clever way, in Google App Engine, to return a wrapped Model instance that only exposes a few of the original properties, and does not allow saving the instance back to the datastore?

I'm not looking for ways of actually enforcing these rules, obviously it'll still be possible to change the instance by digging through its `__dict__` etc. I just want a way to avoid accidental exposure/changing of data.

My initial thought was to do this (I want to do this for a public version of a `User` model):

```
class PublicUser(db.Model):
    display_name = db.StringProperty()

    @classmethod
    def kind(cls):
        return 'User'

    def put(self):
        raise SomeError()
```

Unfortunately, GAE maps the kind to a class early on, so if I do `PublicUser.get_by_id(1)` I will actually get a `User` instance back, not a `PublicUser` instance.

Also, the idea is that it should *at least* appear to be a `Model` instance so that I can pass it around to code that does not know about the fact that it is a "dumbed-down" version. Ultimately I want to do this so that I can use my generic data exposure functions on the read-only version, so that they only expose public information about the user.

---

#### Update

I went with icio's solution. Here's the code I wrote for copying the properties from the `User` instance over to a `PublicUser` instance:

```
class User(db.Model):
    # ...
    # code
    # ...

    def as_public(self):
        """Returns a PublicUser version of this object.
        
        """
        props = self.properties()

        pu = PublicUser()
        for prop in pu.properties().values():
            # Only copy properties that exist for both the PublicUser model and
            # the User model.
            if prop.name in props:
                # This line of code sets the property of the PublicUser
                # instance to the value of the same property on the User
                # instance.
                prop.__set__(pu, props[prop.name].__get__(self, type(self)))

        return pu
```

Please comment if this isn't a good way of doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you not create a method within your `User` class which instantiates a `ReadOnlyUser` object and copies the values of member variables over as appropriate? Your call would be something like `User.get_by_id(1).readonly()` with the `readonly` method defined in the following form:

```
class User(db.Model):
    def readonly(self):
        return ReadOnlyUser(self.name, self.id);
```

Or you could perhaps have your `User` class extend another class with methods to do this automatically based on some static vars listing properties to copy over, or something.

*P.S. I don't code in Python*

Comment: Yeah that's a pretty straight-forward way to do it =) I might go with this.

Comment: I'll go with this =) I updated my question to include the code I used, for those interested.